# Code to sort based on quantities of a data member occuring

Tags: c++, c++14

The setup is that I have a vector of a class, and I need to sort it by the *quantity* of a data member value, not the value itself. The below code exhibits the correct behavior, and part of that behavior is "stable" sorting where the order of elements should be preserved when possible.

Between the `/*** Starting here ***/` and `/*** Ending here ***/` comments, are there some Standard Library functions and/or classes that can be substituted? Per the tag, the code needs to exist in C++14. Yes, I realize that the MRE is written with C++17 (maybe some 20, but I compiled it as C++17), but the code in question [hopefully] isn't.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
  int fizz = 0;
  int buzz = 0;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &sout, const Foo &obj) {
  return sout << "(" << obj.fizz << ", " << obj.buzz << ")";
}

template <typename Container>
void print(const Container &container, std::ostream &sout = std::cout) {
  std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(sout, " "));
  sout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> large(500, 999);

  std::vector<Foo> devices;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    devices.push_back(Foo{.fizz = dist(prng), .buzz = large(prng)});
  }

  print(devices);
  std::cout << '\n';

  /*** Starting here ***/
  // Counting occurrences
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> counts;
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++index, ++i) {
    counts.emplace_back(index, 0);
  }
  for (auto i : devices) {
    ++counts[i.fizz].second;
  }

  // Descending sort using counts of occurrence of a fizz value
  std::stable_sort(counts.begin(), counts.end(),
                   [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second > b.second; });

  std::vector<int> sort_by(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    sort_by[i] = counts[i].first;
  }
  print(sort_by);  // Prints fizz values in order of descending count
  std::cout << '\n';

  // Sort devices according to highest quantity of fizz
  auto walker = devices.begin();
  for (auto i : sort_by) {
    for (auto it = devices.begin(); it != devices.end(); ++it) {
      if (it->fizz == i) {
        std::iter_swap(walker, it);
        ++walker;
      }
    }
  }
  /*** Ending here ***/

  print(devices);
}
```

Comment: Title changed. There are too many help pages based around asking questions, and the edges of those pages are fuzzy and overlap slightly.

Comment: Is there a reason to not initialise `devices` but rather push_back on an empty container ? Also is `.fizz =` and `.buzz =` necessary ?

Comment: I don't care about those parts of the code (per what I've written); they are set-up for the part I do care about. This is obviously not production code, but a test for an algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

```
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++index, ++i) {
    counts.emplace_back(index, 0);
  }
```

Not sure why you use `index` here which is same as `i` ?

---

```
[](auto a, auto b) { return a.second > b.second; }
for (auto i : sort_by) {
```

`a` and `b`, `i` can be marked `const`.

---

```
 std::vector<int> sort_by(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    sort_by[i] = counts[i].first;
  }
```

Not sure that there's a big improvement, but here's a change anyway.

```
  std::vector<int> sort_by;
  sort_by.reserve(10);
  std::for_each(counts.begin(), counts.end(), [&sort_by](const auto &i) {
    sort_by.push_back(i.first);
  });
```

---

```
for (auto it = devices.begin(); it != devices.end(); ++it) {
  if (it->fizz == i) {
    std::iter_swap(walker, it);
    ++walker;
  }
}
```

Can be made a bit simpler by using range based for loop & address instead of iterator. Note the reference in `&it`.

```
for (auto &it : devices) {
  if (it.fizz == i) {
    std::iter_swap(walker, &it);
    ++walker;
  }
}
```

Comment: The index thing is a hold-over from when `i` and `index` didn't match up. Also outside the area I care about. In range-for where you say i can be marked const, I see marking a copy as const as completely pointless. `std::for_each` is not a bad idea, but universal capture by reference is. I don't like the last change at all.

Comment: You haven't really done a great job at defining what area you care about.. it's in the starting-ending region. // Marking new objects `const` is a good practice, at least where I work. // what's the problem with universal capture by reference ? // Why don't you like the last change at all ?

Comment: My bad on the first one, I thought I'd put all the set-up outside the comments. A copy being marked const is pointless. So what if I modify it? It's a copy. I gain no safety or security in marking it const. The problem with universal capture by reference is exactly that it's universal. It's addressed in Effective Modern C++ Item 31: Avoid default capture modes. They can lead to dangling references and a false sense of security. I don't like the last change at all because I consider it hacky. If I want the iterators, range-based for isn't the right tool.

Comment: no worries // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157523/why-would-you-use-the-keyword-const-if-you-already-know-variable-should-be-const?noredirect=1&lq=1 // Thanks for telling me about universal capture. I fixed it.  // okay.. seems like a matter of taste. I see iterator as a fancy pointer.

Comment: It's not that I know it will be constant or not. It's that I literally don't care if it is or not. **It's a copy.** My original data is untouched. I understand the need for const. I use it when it makes sense. It doesn't in a range-based for loop that's copying the values. Had it been `auto&`, then I'd definitely use const if I didn't intend to modify the values.